# How can I be more specific with this regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python and trying to separate the following string into two strings:

```
'"99233 (I21.4,I50.23), 93010 (I21.4,I50.23)"'

stringA = "99233 (I21.4,I50.23),"
stringB = "93010 (I21.4,I50.23)"
```

I'm using the following expression in python:

```
pattern = re.compile('\d{5}.*[),|"|\n]')
```

So I do the following:

1. there are always 5 numbers, so \d{5}
2. followed by (...alphanumerics...), so .*
3. then there is an end parens and comma and then another set OR there is a new line

But my RE keeps matching the whole line. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the string is always going to be in that format, why not just split by the second `,`?

Comment: Could something like this work: `substrings = str.split(",")`

Comment: Have you tried a non-greedy `.*?` instead of `.*`?

Comment: Also notice you have a whitespace following your comma, which you'll also have to match against.

Comment: Do you actually have the inner `"` and the outer `'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could come up with:

```
import re

string = '99233 (I21.4,I50.23), 93010 (I21.4,I50.23)'
parts = re.split(r'(?<=\)),\ ', string)
print(parts)
# ['99233 (I21.4,I50.23)', '93010 (I21.4,I50.23)']
```

This uses a positive lookbehind and splits on the space.
See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/BD1XjI).

Comment: Thanks I think this could work - do you know how to modify it so it doesn't keep the comma on the end of the first string?

Comment: Modified the answer, just put the comma out of the lookbehind,

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

data = '"99233 (I21.4,I50.23), 93010 (I21.4,I50.23)"'
print re.findall(r'\d{5}.*\(.*?\)', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead:

`\d{5}.*(?=\))`

Additionally you could make this:

`(\d{5})(.*(?=\())(.*)(?=\))`

Then you could grab the 5 digit string with back-reference 1, and the inner-string with back-reference 3

Or you could take it one step further:

`(\d{5})(.*(?=\())(\((\s{1,}\b|\b))(.*?(?=(\s{1,},|,)))(\s{1,},|,)(\s{1,}\b|\b)(.+)(?=\s{1,}\)|\))`

Then you could get the following:

5 digit string: Back-reference 1

Left-hand inner value: Back-reference 5

Right-hand inner value: Back-reference 9

<s>Observe</s>

#### EDIT: spotted a bug, thus removed the link. Here's the new one:

[Regex with test strings](https://regex101.com/r/sJ8sE4/2)